# Why would nuxt axios be calling the wrong server middleware API?

Tags: axios, nuxt.js

I recently split my Nuxt API into several files for easy management. However, it seems that when I make my calls, it sometimes calls into the wrong file.

In my nuxt.config.js, I have

```js
serverMiddleware:[
    {path:"/user-api",handler:"~/api/user.js"},
    {path:"/blog-api",handler:"~/api/blog.js"},
    {path:"/calendar-api",handler:"~/api/calendar.js"},
    {path:"/gallery-api",handler:"~/api/images.js"},
    {path:"/product-api",handler:"~/api/product.js"},
    {path:"/video-api",handler:"~/api/video.js"},
    {path:"/printful-api",handler:"~/api/printful.js"},
    {path:"/review-api",handler:"~/api/reviews.js"},
    {path:"/email-api",handler:"~/api/email.js"},
    {path:"/search-api",handler:"~/api/search.js"},
    {path:"/requirement-api",handler:"~/api/requirements.js"},
  ]
```

Then when I load in my desired page

```js
this.video = await this.$axios.$get('/video-api/title',{params:{title:this.$route.params.title}})
```

It ends up calling the wrong file:

```js
  Error... at async api\requirements.js:55:12
```

Any reason why it would be doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that simply having the same end path causes it confusion. Changing the call (and api obviously) to

```js
this.video = await this.$axios.$get('/video-api/videotitle',{params:{title:this.$route.params.title}})
```

so that the final part of the call is unique, fixes the problem. Can't say it's ideal, but it does work. I found this out because it also had other problems mixing up `blog-api/title` as well

Answer (score 0):

Furthemore, looks like nuxt have a bug when using more than one path  with root path like this:

```
    { path: '/news', handler: '~/serverMiddleware/news'},
    { path: '/post', handler: '~/serverMiddleware/post'},
```

(second will not work on post page reload)
while that is working in any calls:

```
   { path: '/api/news', handler: '~/serverMiddleware/news'},
   { path: '/api/post', handler: '~/serverMiddleware/post'},
```